# Downloading Gifv files for use in AVPlayer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, mp4, avplayer

I've been working with Imgur's api for fetching a retrieving photos but whenever I try and download a gifv, or webm I can't download or play it. Now Imgur's api has no direct way to download the gifv as an mp4. Is their anyway I can convert the downloaded gifv to a playable mp4 in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is their anyway I can convert the downloaded gifv to a playable mp4 in Swift?

Not really.

`gifv` is not a real file format but a set of HTML5 rules that imgur uses on their webpages to deliver their new GIFs: the server decides which file it delivers upon several criteria like bandwidth.

`gifv` is actually a wrapper on their server containing a WebM file, a MP4 and a re-encoded GIF.

You can't use it as it is, a GIFV is only playable via an HTML code snippet generated by [this imgur page](http://imgur.com/vidgif).